# How to return array of C struct from C function to go?

Tags: arrays, go, struct, cgo, gccgo

I have a C function which will return an array of structure to go function.
How can I receive the array of structure and interpret or cast to go structure?

Here is the code snippet

```
typedef struct student{  
    nameStruct name;  
    addressStruct address;  
} studentStruct;

typedef struct name{
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
} nameStruct;

typedef struct address{
    char location[40];
    int    pin;
}addressStruct;


student* getAllStudents(){
   //Allocate memory for N number of students
   student *pStudent= (struct student*)(N* sizeof(struct student));
   //populate the array
   return pStudent;
}
```

I need to get the pStudent array in my go code

```
package main

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I.
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L. -lkeyboard
#include "keyboard.h"
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
)

type student struct {
    name string
    ID int
}

func main() {
    s := student{} //Need to know how to decide the length of the struct array
    s = C.getAllStudents() //?????


}
```

Can some one help me with code snippet?

Comment: There's a lot of missing functionality here, covering a lot of basic areas. What part are you asking about?

Comment: what is the best way  of casting C structure into Go structure? considering there can be different data types in the C structure.

Comment: If the data types are different, you need to copy/convert those to their respective fields. For example, Go strings are not the same as C strings, so you can't "cast" those, you need to copy the characters from the C `char*` to the Go `string`

Comment: I am aware of that, that's why I was looking for any other short cut which can directly cast or map C struct to Golang struct

Comment: I have added a complex C struct studentStruct in my original post. Can some one add a code snippet to interpret this C struct in Go code?

Comment: What do you mean by "interpret" the C struct? You said that you are aware that you need to copy/convert the data to use native Go structures, but are looking for a shortcut. You can access the struct directly as type `C.struct_student` if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cgo: How to pass struct array from c to go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925179/cgo-how-to-pass-struct-array-from-c-to-go)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the out paramters, and the way for C struct -> Go struct is thus:

```
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Point{
    float x;
    float y;
}Point;

void GetPoint(void **ppPoint) {
   Point *pPoint= (Point *)malloc(sizeof(Point));
   pPoint->x=0.5f;
   pPoint->y=1.5f;
   *ppPoint = pPoint;
}
*/
import "C"

import "unsafe"

type Point struct {
    x float32
    y float32
}

func main() {
    var ppoint unsafe.Pointer
    C.GetPoint(&ppoint)
    point := *(*Point)(ppoint)
    println(point.x, point.y)
}
```

Comment: In fact, I suggest use json string between C and Golang.

Comment: converting all different data types to json string before sending to Golang will take additional transformation logic what I was trying to avoid.